# Conflicting methods: in how many ways can we distribute 5 aces among 4 people?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Assuming that we do not replace the cards, the answer seems to be $5*4*3*2$ ways to distribute the cards. We stop at each person, and multiply the number of cards that are still available. Great, makes sense.

However, I would really appreciate some insight on why another procedure doesn't work, i.e. if I was to instead work card by card. Let us take the first ace: it can be given to $4$ different people. The next ace can be given to 4 different people too. And so on. This would suggest that there are $4*4*4*4*4 = 4^5$ possible ways of giving out the aces. I have reason to believe this method is wrong, can anyone explain specifically what is wrong with it?

Comment: Must every person get at least one ace?

Comment: I suppose if I said no, then the second method works?

Answer (score 4):

In the second case, all the aces might end up with one person and others might not get any card.

Comment: Ahh yes, that makes sense doesn't it!

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of information in the OP, let us assume that the people are distinguishable, and the five aces are not.

Assuming **no restrictions** on how many aces each person gets:

Take the **five** aces and add **three** identical dividers. Arrange these **eight** items in a row in (blank) ways, taking into account that the three identical dividers can be re-arranged without changing the overall order, as well as the five identical aces.

Person #1 gets the aces in front of the first divider, Person #2 the aces between the first and second divider, and so on.

If everyone gets at least one ace, then do that with the first four aces;  then give the one remaining ace to one of the four persons.

For much more on this technique see "Stars and Bars combinatorics" Ignore the US Civil War hits...